# Solving a definite integral with u substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$\displaystyle{\int_0^4} x \sqrt{36-x^2}dx$

This is a pretty basic question but I have something very wrong with my idea of U substitution. So what I do is set u = $ 36-x^2 $ which then gives me $\displaystyle du =-2xdx$ So what I do next is divide by -2 and get -$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}du = dx$ So then you need to change your bounds which would I think give you
$\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2} {\int_{36}^{20}} \sqrt{u}$ du if you plug the original bounds back into the equation for u. So I get the integral to be $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}u^{3/2}$ after integrating. I did flip the bounds so 36 is on top and 20 is on bottom and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$ becomes positive. I evaluate on the bounds and I am getting $\displaystyle \frac{216}{3}-\frac{40\sqrt{5}}{3}$ which I know to be incorrect. Where am I going wrong?

The correct answer based on my book is $\displaystyle \frac{21\sqrt{21}-5\sqrt{5}}{3}$

Comment: Why do you think the result you state is wrong?

Comment: Because my textbook has something much different I can provide what its saying is the correct answer if needed

Comment: $\frac{216}{3}$ is well-known as $72$.

Comment: I updated what my textbook has as the correct answer

Comment: See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*sqrt%2836-x%5E2%29+from+0+to+4).

Comment: That's interesting I think the book may have the incorrect answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you mean $-\dfrac12 du=\color{red} x dx$?

Comment: Yes I did that's actually a typo but I think my text book has a printing error. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing:  A study guide or a computerized grader is expecting to see $72 - \frac{40\sqrt{5}}{3}$.  But $\frac{216}{3} = 72$, so these are equivalent.

Comment: That's what I thought but I'm genuinely confused to what I did wrong. I updated the question with what the book says is correct

Comment: @ManofSteam : I suspect your book has an error.  Since 21 and 5 in their answer differ by 16, as do 36 and 20 in your work, I suspect the listed answer is from a variant of a similar integral appearing in an earlier edition or earlier draft of the text, that has erroneously survived to printing.

Comment: I think you are right on that. Thanks a lot for the help!